# VBA Excel-How to restrict users not to paste on specific rows?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel like shown below which is a sharedExcel.

[image]

Now i should not allow paste option for the rows which have backcolour as **GRAY**(These are not fixed at runtime any row may get GRAY colour). As it sharedExcel and  i can't use the Lock property. Any help wouls be appreciated greatly.

Comment: Password Protected Range ☺ based on the `Colour Gray`.. During run time you have to make sure which rows gets Gray, then only you can do the copy pasting if you follow my tip. Otherwise how do you expect the code to know which cell should be restricted? So the work flow is: Make Gray -> Protect -> No Pasting. Or can the S.NO become a factor to decide if the row can be protected?

Comment: @bonCondigo, hi thank u for your response but i can't use your workflow as i am making my excel as **Shared**. Take a case that at runtime a gray coloured row may get white colour at that time i have to allow pasting on that row. to do this i have to make sheet unprotect and then allowing pasting but one we can't make Unprotect when excel is in Shared mode. If we do so it will throw an error like `Runtime Error '1004' object doesn't support this method`

Comment: Well you have sort of done what I mentioned for `having the condition for checking the colour` :) Glad you got it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time on this problem i have coded following lines. It work's fine. Here i have taken another spreadsheet called **PasteSheet** for coding purpose but i am not showing it to user at any moment.

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Application.CutCopyMode Then
    SelectedRow = ActiveCell.Row
    With Sheets("PasteSheet")
        .Activate
        .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        CR = Selection.Rows.Count
    End With
    Worksheets("ActualSheet").Activate
    For k = SelectedRow To (SelectedRow + CR)
        If Worksheets("ActualSheet").Cells(k, 30).Interior.Color = RGB(215, 215, 215) Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            MsgBox "Pasting is not allowed here!"
            'Clearing data in PasteSheet
            Worksheets("PasteSheet").Cells.ClearContents
            Worksheets("ActualSheet").Activate
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
End If
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Using a color as a property that is used to check true / false is bad behaviour. 
You can get around this by for example adding a column (hidden if needed) with 0 / 1 or TRUE / FALSE which you make accessible by for example a combobox (then you can still adapt the color into gray by clicking this cbb box).

The you can check on a dynamically composed range via a Sheet event on_Change. 
The basic syntax for the sheet event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Set range dynamically instead of this hard coded example 
If Not Intersect(Target, Thisworkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A10")) Is Nothing Then 
    'Do something 
End If
End Sub
```